# Using Selenium to run webdriver (Chrome) and setting up proxy to log browsed URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to automation. I wanted to know how we can use selenium webdriver and python together, so that when the webdriver uses Chrome to launch the website, a proxy gets attached to the chrome webdriver to monitor user actions.
Proxy can be a ran using 'jar'or an 'exe'. Please suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver 
PROXY = "23.23.23.23:3128" # IP:PORT or HOST:PORT 
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
 chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY) 
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
 chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
```

This is a way how to attach proxy to a browser, I am personally using a for loop from my txt file where i have written all proxies .. ( code doesnt look good cuz typing it from a phone ) but thats the way how to acctualy do it ^.^ , another thing as I can see you are completly new in programming, because Jar is for Java files , Exe is executable file and python is using .py at the end of its sctipts ... and last thing about monitoring ... well selenium is a browser similar to chrome, but its controlled by python ... you cant monitor whats going on with python much ( alike a beginner ) but the esiest way would be that you just make a script that will make a screenshot every few seconds or basicly look for a tutorial how to make a keylogger ^.^ I hope i helped you ^.^ if no ask me questions in a comment section, if I did please lick that check icon and ^ button
- thanks you ^.^

Comment: Great! It works.. all credit to you. One last thing - once the browser has loaded the web page, when I click on some link in the loaded web page, it takes me to different URL. How can I capture that URL using webdriver?

Comment: Well there should be a function thsts getting your current url ... i think its webdriver.current_url ... but not sure ... when i come home i can loom forit if you will still struggle ... but try something like that current_url or google selenium get current url

Comment: I will try that! Cheers!